# MySQL Query to not select the same ID

Tags: mysql

I have the query to select similar keywords within the database. However, the query is selecting its own ID as the one I'm trying to find similar recommendations for. I just want the recommendations and not the duplicated ID. I have tried '!=' and '<>' after productID, but this seems to break it.

So for this one, it will select ID 22 as well as its similar products. I don't want it picking 22 however.

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: `SELECT prodID FROM keywords WHERE prodID != 22 AND attributeID...`

Comment: Though I'd bet you can do this much more efficiently with a join.

Comment: Yeah. Stop. Read about JOINs. Go.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you've written. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you've already tried; the description leaves a bit open to interpretation.  I can say that this *should* work:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products
 WHERE prodID IN (SELECT prodID 
                    FROM keywords 
                   WHERE attributeID IN (SELECT attributeID 
                                           FROM keywords a 
                                          WHERE prodID = 22
                                        )
                     AND prodID <> 22
                 )
 LIMIT 4;
```

If this is something you've tried and it didn't work, then you'll need to specify in what way it didn't work.  (Error message?  Data incorrect (and if so, how)?

Comment: You say about a join.. would this be easier?

Comment: Eh... it could be rewritten based on a join.  Unless you see a performance problem with one or the other, I'd use whichever seems to you that it more intuitively reflects the intent of the logic.

Comment: Yeah, see joins again - and note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I did not understand the question but is it not as simple as below:

SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodID
IN 
(SELECT prodID FROM keywords WHERE proid<>22)) LIMIT 4;

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't like nesting subqueries that much, but if you have to go with that, you can achieve your result by adding 'prodID <> 22' just before the LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE prodID IN 
  (SELECT prodID FROM keywords WHERE attributeID IN 
    (SELECT attributeID FROM keywords a WHERE prodID = 22)) 
AND prodID <> 22 LIMIT 4;
```

If you're not bound to that, please notice that you can achieve better performance by using **joins**:

> A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better—a fact that is not specific to MySQL Server alone.
>
> Prior to SQL-92, outer joins did not exist, so subqueries were the
>   only way to do certain things. Today, MySQL Server and many other
>   modern database systems offer a wide range of outer join types

.

You may want to look at these to improve your queries performance: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rewriting-subqueries.html